A very interesting formula for $\sin x$

Prove that for all $(n,t,x) \in \mathbb{N}^{*}\times \mathbb{R}\times]0,\pi[$ : $\sin(x) = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k-1}\sin kx \right)\left( 1-2t\cos x+t^{2} \right)+t^{n}\left( \sin((n+1)x)-t\sin(nx) \right)$
Hint : Calculate $\sum_{k=1}^n t^k e^{ikx}$

I have genuinely no idea on how to prove this equality. By working out with the given hint, I find:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n t^k e^{ikx}=te^{ix} \times \frac{1-t^ne^{inx}}{1-te^{ix}}$$
But this leads me to nowhere. I would gladly appreciate some help.

Rather than actually summing it, you should separate the exponential into real and imaginary parts, as the desired formula is also a finite sum.

Divide the last equation by $t$ and then take the imaginary part. This will solve your problem.

The LHS is independent of $n$, so induction on $n$ is also straightforward. Part of the induction step could be to show that
$$0 \overset?= -t^n\sin((n+1)x)\cdot 2t\cos x + t^{n+1}\sin((n+2)x) + t^{n+1}\sin(nx) $$

What is interesting about this formula?

it's one that helps you calculate $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{sin(kx)}{k}$

Thanks, with the help that was given to me on the comments, I have finally managed to solve it, so here's the answer.
We have
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k}e^{ ikx } &= te^{ ix }\times \dfrac{1-t^{n}e^{ inx }}{1-te^{ ix }} \\
\end{align}
As such
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k-1}\sin(kx) = \mathrm{Im}(e^{ ix }\times \dfrac{1-t^{n}e^{ inx }}{1-te^{ ix }})
$$
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Im}(e^{ ix }\times \dfrac{1-t^{n}e^{ inx }}{1-te^{ ix }})&= \mathrm{Im}\left( (\cos x+i\sin(x))\times \dfrac{1-t^{n}\cos nx -it^{n}\sin(nx)}{1-t\cos x-it\sin x} \right) \\
&= \mathrm{Im}\left( (\cos x+i\sin x)\times \dfrac{(1-t^{n}\cos nx - it^{n}\sin nx)}{(1-t\cos x)^{2}+t^{2}\sin ^{2}(x)}\times(1-t\cos x+it\sin x) \right) \\
&= \dfrac{t\cos x\sin x - t^{n+1}\cos nx \cos x \sin x-t^{n}\cos x \sin nx + t^{'n+1}\cos ^{2}x \sin nx + \sin x -t \cos x \sin x - t^{n}\cos nx \sin x + t^{n+1}\cos x \cos nx \sin x - t^{n+1}\sin ^{2}x\sin nx}{(1-t\cos x)^{2}+t^{2}\sin ^{2}(x)} \\
&= \dfrac{\sin x + t^{n+1}x\sin nx - t^{n}(\cos x\sin nx + \sin x \cos nx)}{t^{2} - 2t\cos x +1} \\
&= \dfrac{\sin x + t^{n+1}x \sin nx - t^{n}\sin((n+1)x)}{t^{2}-2t\cos x +1} \\
&= \dfrac{\sin x  - t^{n}(\sin((n+1)x)-t\sin nx)}{t^{2}-2t\cos x+1}
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$
\sin x = \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n}t^{k-1}\sin(kx) \right) (t^{2}-2t\cos x +1) + t^{n}(\sin((n+1)x)-t\sin(nx))
$$
